# How do I query pouchDb and add the document info to Redux Store

Tags: reactjs, redux, pouchdb

I am new to Reactjs, Redux and Pouchdb. I am using the example https://github.com/jrzerr/react-redux-pouchdb

I could see the remotedb synced, but do not know how to query the db and add it to the Redux Store

Any sample code or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: querying db: https://pouchdb.com/, add to redux store: https://redux.js.org/

Comment: Any simple code would help!

Comment: Thank you @azium, I was able to solve it